# JavaScript Error: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript

I have a script that performce this action:

```
document.getElementById("bildfram2").style.backgroundImage = "url("bilder[count]")";
```

I have an array looking like this:

```
var bilder = ["../img/startsida/nature1.jpg","../img/startsida/nature2.jpg","../img/startsida/nature3.jpg","../img/startsida/nature4.jpg"];
```

I get this error from the first line of code:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Can someone help me fix the issue! Thanks!

Comment: @MelanciaUK "bilder" is German for "images".

Comment: @MannfromReno That wont work. It will set the backgroun-image to bilder[count] insted of one of the images in the array...

Comment: "url(" + bilder[count] + ")";

Comment: @melpomene It is acctualy images in Swedish :) (Im from sweden)

Comment: @ne1410s Thanks! That was the solution! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate a string and a variable with `+`

```
document.getElementById("bildfram2").style.backgroundImage = 
    "url(" + bilder[count] + ")";
```